# How to fold the code in Xcode Swift iOS by default

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, code-folding

I know that we can fold the code by using Option+Command+Shift+LeftKey. But what I want to know that, can we do something to fold the code by default in every View Controller's class that means whenever we search for or open any class it's code is already folded.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Not something you can set as default. The closest you can get is using <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>left</kbd> to fold all in the current file.

Comment: Okay thank you, they might think of it in the future.